# I keep getting segmentation fault error and I'm not sure where the issue is

Tags: c

*context:* I have this college assignment I should something like rush hour game..  I have a park lot with cars in it, with a specific car (symboled with *) that should leave the lot (exit is at the middle line extreme left column). I should move the cars and get it out.
for example, here is a given lot:

```
|1||1|| || || |
| || ||2||2||2|
| || ||*||*||*|
|3||3|| || || |
|3||3|| || || |
```

First thing, I need to ask the user to select a car to move, check if it even do exist in the lot, and if not, to ask him again to select a car. Here is the `SelectCar` function:

```
char SelectCar(char lot[MAX_LOT_LENGTH][MAX_LOT_LENGTH], int Length){
    char car;
    bool exists = false;
    printf("Enter the car you want to move:\n");
    scanf("%c",&car);
    for (int i = 0; i< Length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<Length; j++){
            if (lot[i][j] == car) {
                exists = true;
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    if(!exists) {
        printf("Invalid car id! enter again:\n");
        car = SelectCar(lot,Length);
    }
    printf("car selected\n");
    return car;
}
```

When I run the code, it skips the `scanf` function (It doesn't even ask to enter a car), so when it goes the for loop, `"car"` doesn't even exist in the lot, so it re-enters the `SelectCar` function, and when it reaches the `scanf` (the second time) it just crashes and gives me this error":
*`/home/p10303/.vpl_launcher.sh: line 12: 1904456 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./vpl_execution`*

I'm not sure what to do (I don't even understand what the issue is)

*note: lot and length are defined and received by the user..*

Comment: Make sure `Length` is <= `MAX_LOT_LENGTH`. Then debug/print to know if it crashes before or after `if(!exists)`.

Comment: `Length` is smaller than `MAX_LOT_LENGTH`, and no it crashes right at the beginning of the for loops I checked that..

Comment: you need to post a [mcve]

Comment: Another thing, `%d` will need more than one byte, so change it to `scanf("%c", car);` or makes car an `Int`

Comment: And if you can provide a working example then we can help you move faster, right now I just read your code, and do some imagination while my eyes are closed.

Comment: Where is the code that calls `SelectCar`? I see that it has a recursive call and unless proven otherwise `lot` and `length` are unintialized.

Comment: Thank you guys It doesn't give me this error anymore, but when I run it it skips the scanf function and goes through the whole `SelectCar` function, re-enters the function and then it actually ask for an input..

Comment: Can anyone help me why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure what to do

Save time and enable all compiler warnings to quickly see troubles with `char car; ...  scanf("%d",car);`

`"%d"` in `scanf()` expects a matching pointer to an `int`.

Comment: @HermitZ Code still has trouble with `char car; ...    scanf("%d",&car);`.  [Save time and enable all compiler warnings to quickly see troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74818223/2410359).  I am not clear why you updated with `char *` with `"%d"`.

Comment: sorry must've been by accident I re-changed it to %d